# difference between skewness formulas

Tags: statistics

I started learning statistics recently. I got problem while learning skewness & kurtosis concept i.e in my search for formulas regarding skewness & kurtosis it is showing two different formulas and don't understand when to use which.

And the same problem for kurtosis is also having when to use lengthy formula and when to use small.

can any one please give me clarification,so it is very helpful to me please.

THANKING YOU IN ANTICIPATION

Comment: Your question seems to be more about statistics than about programming. If that is the case it might better fit to [CrossValidated.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com).